# Is it possible for Azure Custom Vision to analyze a video stream and count wheels on vehicle

Tags: c#, azure, machine-learning, video-streaming, microsoft-custom-vision

I have a video feed from a remote camera, we would like to have a solution that looks at the video feed and counts the wheels on any vehicles that pass through its views. From what I have been reading this would be quite easy using images, but I can find nothing about from a video feed. Any help would be appreciated. Environment in C# WinForms using Azure as its backend for processing and storage etc

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble with the same problem. I have not solved it yet in code. But I can try to help explain it conceptually.

If you watch this video, they are counting the object when the centroid passes a given line. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgbS_csjxhk&ab_channel=Nodeflux

The way I think you should approach your problem is similar.

1. Train a model to recognize vehicle wheels.
2. Implement that model. When you use the model, it will return the coordinates of the image bounding box. Here's an abridged output from [Azure Custom Vision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/quickstarts/object-detection?tabs=visual-studio&pivots=programming-language-csharp) "fork: 98.2% [ 0.111609578, 0.184719115, 0.6607002, 0.6637112 ]"+
3. Given the polygon output in the previous step, calculate its centroid.
4. Determine the direction the wheels will pass through the video feed, up-down or left-right. Create a rectangle that covers this area.
5. Create a function that determines when the centroid crosses that rectangle in the desired direction. IE when Centroid goes from < Rectangle to > Rectangle in X or Y.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Fantastic idea, along with the next answer I will be attempting this. If I come up with a solution I will share with you if you'd like

Answer (score 1):

You could design a client-side algorithm to grab keyframes and send them to computer vision, or you could train a custom model in Azure Machine Learning.

But there's an easier solution if you don't want any of those ways: You could use video indexer to get your vehicles' keyframes and export those images to computer vision.

Here is something that could help you if you're interested:

-The idea: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/combine-the-power-of-video-indexer-and-computer-vision/

-Docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-video-indexer/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-video-indexer/scenes-shots-keyframes

Have a nice day, greetings!